# How to slide a listview by interacting with seekbar

Tags: android-listview, android-seekbar

I have a listview and a seekbar, i want the listview to react accroding to the interaction with the seekbar.

For ex :- if the seekbar is dragged to either ends, the listview should automatically go up or down.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the list view method: 
[smoothScrollToPosition(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int))
and [OnSeekBarChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html)

Set an OnSeekBarChangeListener on your seekbar. 
In [onProgressChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html#onProgressChanged(android.widget.SeekBar,%20int,%20boolean)) add code using smoothScrollToPosition to update the listvew position.
Something like this:

```
public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    listView.smoothScrollToPosition(progress); //assuming you have a 1 seekbar position for each row in the list, otherwise you'll need to do some calculation to compute the new list view position.
}
```

alternatively, you could use the onStopTrackingTouch method if you only want to scroll to the final position the user touched in the seekbar.